# Не ставится время из базы данных, использую formatDate

Tags: php

Вот часть кода из index.php

```
 <?php echo formatDate($row['date']); ?>
```

А вот код самой функции

```
 function formatDate($date) {
 return date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($date));
 }
```

Comment: что на выходе, и что на входе.

Comment: @teran не понял вас

Comment: @DaniilKrylov, что содержит переменная `$date` и что выводиться в функции `formatDate()`

Comment: @teran переменная содержит дату из базы данных, функция formatDate() выводит January 1, 1970, 3:00, а должна выводить нормальную дату

Comment: сделайте `print_r()` или вардамп, а не из БД копируйте

Comment: @teran Она автоматически добавляется в запись при ее создании

Comment: @teran https://dsmp.su/

Comment: `<? var_dump($row['date']); ?>` перед выводом даты добавьте, и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: @teran выдает null

Comment: тогда ищите, где дату потеряли. в приведенном коде проблем нет.